# Initialize pageObject without creating @BeforeMethod

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Learning POM in selenium and trying to understand this behaviour. When I set up my test class like this:

```
public class HomePageTests extends BaseTest {
    private HomePage homePage;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setupTest() {
        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkPageTitleTest() {
        //act
        homePage.clickOnMainPageIconButton();

        //get
        String pageTitle = homePage.getMainPageTitle(driver);

        //verify
        assertThat(pageTitle).isEqualTo(HOME_PAGE_TITLE);
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working as intended. However when I tried to create without @BeforeMethod

```
public class HomePageTests extends BaseTest {
    private HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);

    @Test
    public void checkPageTitleTest() {
        //act
        homePage.clickOnMainPageIconButton();

        //get
        String pageTitle = homePage.getMainPageTitle(driver);

        //verify
        assertThat(pageTitle).isEqualTo(HOME_PAGE_TITLE);
    }
}
```

I always receive this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null`

This is how my HomePage looks like:

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage{
    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(className = "header__logo__link")
    WebElement mainPageLogo;

    public void clickOnMainPageIconButton(){
        mainPageLogo.click();
    }

    public String getMainPageTitle(WebDriver driver){
        return driver.getTitle();
    }

}
```

What can I do to get rid of this repeated block of `@BeforeMethod`. Link to my [current repository](https://github.com/mpaasternak/CeneoAutomation) with project if I miss something that might be crucial to described issue.

Tried to create initialize class within HomePage but this was already marked as error by IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line

```
private HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
```

you have to understand the logic of static and non-static variables.

you have initialised your non-static HomePage object on the class level.

> After class loading, initialization of the class takes place which
> means initializing all static members of the class. As a result
> no-static method will not get initialize.

Here you are not using the java main method for execution, the actual execution is via TestNG framework.

**Solution 1:** Make HomePage static

```
 private static HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
```

**Solution 2:** Initilize non-static object on @BeforeClass or @BeforeTest annotation

```
    public class HomePageTests extends BaseTest {
        private HomePage homePage;
    
        @BeforeClass
        public void setupTest() {
            homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void checkPageTitleTest() {
            //act
            homePage.clickOnMainPageIconButton();
            //get
            String pageTitle = homePage.getMainPageTitle(driver);
            //verify
            assertThat(pageTitle).isEqualTo(HOME_PAGE_TITLE);
        } 
}
```

**Your code:**
https://github.com/mpaasternak/CeneoAutomation
[image]

Comment: Tried your solution and added static to homePage variable in testclass however it already asked to make WebDriver variable static as well. However this does not solve issue as I receive same error as I described. For me it looks like PageFactory.initElements(driver,this); is not initialized in HomePage.class which extends BasePage.

Comment: @lobsang plz share your complete code on git. The same code is working fine for me. But there is one logic that I'm unable to understand you are initializing the driver on BeforeSuite and then you are opening the URL on BeforeMethod and again after that, you are closing the session at  AfterMethod annotation. This logic seems weird as it will destroy object for the second test and as result it will throw error.

Comment: Just pushed uncommited changes, rookie mistake as I thought I pushed all changes last time before posting my question.
Regarding aftermethod annotation - got it from one course and logic behind was as explained there to create new browser before every test and after test to clear it but as you mentioned it I kinda realize that I initialize driver once and after every test I am tearing it down so for this to work as explained I would need to change from BeforeSuite to BeforeMethod annotation.